# How go to controller action correctly, using haml form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

When I go to set_answer action(localhost:3000/staff/set_answer/) from answer action(localhost:3000/staff/answer/) , I get this url:
localhost:3000/staff/answer/set_answer but this is wrong URL . How get this url:
localhost:3000/staff/set_answer

this is how i set action where should go parameters

```
%form{ :controller => "staffs", :action => "setanswer", :method => "post"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Rails, you should implement a form using the [`form_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) helper method.

Try this:

```
= form_tag staff_setanswer_path do
  // ...
  = submit_tag
```

or this:

```
= form_tag :controller => :staff, :action => :setanswer do
  // ...
  = submit_tag
```

And if you want to stay with a Haml form, try this:

```
%form{:action => staff_setanswer_path, :method => :post}
```

I'm guessing routes here. You might adapt the _path helper here and there.